# How to register icon for custom extention

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-cascades

Can I register an icon in Blackberry for my own file extension (*.mgn), so that my icon will appear in the file manager and in the file selection dialog instead of the standard icon? I used Invocation Framework to register the extension itself.

I tried to specify the icon in the config.xml but failed

```
<rim:invoke-target id="MyExtMgn">
    <type>APPLICATION</type>
    <icon>
          <image>img/mgn-icon.png</image>
    </icon>
    <filter>
        <action>bb.action.OPEN</action>
        <mime-type>*</mime-type>

        <property var="uris" value="file://"/>
        <property var="exts" value="mgn"/>
    </filter>
</rim:invoke-target>
```

Comment: I was told the service desk Blackberry: Unfortunately this is not possible with the current APIs.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'failed'?  Are you just not seeing your custom icon, or is your app not showing up in the list of targets.  The developer documentation for this can be found here: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_1/receiving_invocation.html#ufa1342040721425